# nvarchar column query to varchar column returning no values in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server

I am performing a query to find visually identical values from two columns, but not receiving any of the matches. One column is of type `nvarchar`, and the other is `varchar`.  Here is the example:

`Database_1.Table_1` contains `column_1` with the following values:

```
1
2
3
4
```

`Database_2.Table_2` contains `column_2` with the following values:

```
1
2
3
```

I am performing the query:

```
SELECT TRIM([Column_1])
FROM [Database_1].[dbo].[Table_1] 
WHERE TRIM([Column_1]) IN (SELECT TRIM([Column_2]) 
                           FROM [Database_2].[dbo].[Table_2])
```

I get no matches. `Column_1` is `nvarchar` and `Column_2` is `varchar` and I have confirmed there are trailing spaces, which is why I attempted to fix this through the use of `TRIM`. Is there something else I could do to get them to match?

Additional info regarding the data in follow up to comments:

I created column_2 in table_2 by exporting a subset of column_1 from table_1 to a CSV, running some formatting via python which included conversion into string values, then importing the formatted values of the CSV into the database to create column_2 in table_2.

Comment: I cant see any problem, can you provide some data example? varchar and nvarchar should have no casting problem.

Comment: databse1 and database2 are on same server?

Comment: the things you think are spaces may be some other non printing character.

Comment: I updated the post to include additional information regarding the values.  The values are just strings of numbers.  If there is a way to give samples, here is an example from one cell with CTRL+V used in between the quotes: "16986933 "  If there are non-printing characters, perhaps there is a way to debug?

Comment: cast the columns to varbinary and look at the character codes in hex

Comment: can you please provide an example?  I am not familiar with this technique.

Comment: Just simply cast(TRIM([Column_1]) as varbinary(20))